# 301 redirect from old domains url to new domains new url

Tags: reactjs, xml, web-config, http-status-code-301

URL redirections are not happening. I have 2 different url(old/new)

**old:** https://olddomain.com/oldarticlecategory/

**new:** https://newdomain.com/newurlcategory/

**Note:** I've already created a rule that redirects articles in the old category to articles in the new domain. Below is the code snippet to configure the code. Now I have to write one more rule on top of this. Any suggestions. I'm using **web.config**

```
<rule name="redirect personalities" enabled="true">
<match url="^oldarticlecategory/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="https://olddomain.com/oldarticlecategory" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://newdomain.com/newurlcategory/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

The above code snippet I wrote to achieve below.

**Old Url:** https://olddomain.com/oldarticlecategory/article-details

**New Url:** https://newdomain.com/newurlcategory/article-details

Comment: I don't understand the question here. You need to create another rule doing what exactly?

Comment: @ThomasArdal - I actually wanted to create one more rule for below redirections. from old url to new url redirections.

old url: https://olddomain.com/oldarticlecategory/
new url: https://newdomain.com/newurlcategory/

Comment: But the rule you have put in the sample does just that, right? Redirect from the old URL to the new one.